# Neo4j is there a way to create a variable number of relationships in one cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to create N nodes with a sequential relationship between each of them.

Think of my requirement as creating a workflow for a user. On the UI end it can send an array of json objects that must relate to each other sequentially. For example:

`{steps: [ {name: 'step 1'}, {name: 'step2'}, {name: 'step3'}] }`

What I want from the above json is to create 3 nodes and have them sequentially linked

`(step 1)-[:has_next_step]->(step 2)-[:has_next_step]->(step 3)`

Is there a quick way of doing this? Keep in mind my example has 3 nodes, but in reality I may have anywhere from 5-15 steps so the cypher query must be able to handle this variable input. Note that I have control over the input as well so if there is an easier json params variable I can use that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, the only issue you will face is when iterating the collection of steps you will not be able to recognise the node representing the element before in the collection.

So a bit of hacking, you can use a timestamp in the beginning of the query to act as identifier :

```
WITH {steps: [ {name: 'step 1'}, {name: 'step2'}, {name: 'step3'}] } AS object
WITH object.steps AS steps, timestamp() AS identifier
UNWIND range(1, size(steps)-1) AS i
MERGE (s:Step {id: identifier + "_" + (i-1)}) SET s.name = (steps[i-1]).name
MERGE (s2:Step {id: identifier + "_" + (i)}) SET s2.name = (steps[i]).name
MERGE (s)-[:NEXT]->(s2)
```

Explanation :

I iterate the collection of steps with `UNWIND`, in order to recognize each node representing an already iterated step, I use a dummy identifier being the timestamp of the transaction + "_" + the sequence cursor.

At large scale you would better use your own identifiers (like a generated uuid on client side) and have an index/unique constraint on it.

[image]

More Advanced :

You have a User node and want to attach steps to it (context : the user didn't had any steps connected to it before)

Create a dummy user:

```
CREATE (u:User {login:"me"})
```

Create steps list and attach to user

```
WITH {steps: [ {name: 'step 1'}, {name: 'step2'}, {name: 'step3'}] } AS object
WITH object.steps AS steps, timestamp() AS identifier
UNWIND range(1, size(steps)-1) AS i
MERGE (s:Step {id: identifier + "_" + (i-1)}) SET s.name = (steps[i-1]).name
MERGE (s2:Step {id: identifier + "_" + (i)}) SET s2.name = (steps[i]).name
MERGE (s)-[:NEXT]->(s2)
WITH identifier + "_" + (size(steps)-1) AS lastStepId, identifier + "_0" AS firstStepId
MATCH (user:User {login:"me"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[r:LAST_STEP]->(oldStep)
DELETE r
WITH firstStepId, lastStepId, oldStep, user
MATCH (s:Step {id: firstStepId})
MATCH (s2:Step {id: lastStepId})
MERGE (user)-[:LAST_STEP]->(s)
WITH s2, collect(oldStep) AS old
FOREACH (x IN old | MERGE (s2)-[:NEXT]->(x))
```

[image]

Context, (run the same query but with different names for steps to visually see the diff) : The user has already steps attached to him :

```
WITH {steps: [ {name: 'second 1'}, {name: 'second 2'}, {name: 'second 3'}] } AS object
WITH object.steps AS steps, timestamp() AS identifier
UNWIND range(1, size(steps)-1) AS i
MERGE (s:Step {id: identifier + "_" + (i-1)}) SET s.name = (steps[i-1]).name
MERGE (s2:Step {id: identifier + "_" + (i)}) SET s2.name = (steps[i]).name
MERGE (s)-[:NEXT]->(s2)
WITH identifier + "_" + (size(steps)-1) AS lastStepId, identifier + "_0" AS firstStepId
MATCH (user:User {login:"me"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[r:LAST_STEP]->(oldStep)
DELETE r
WITH firstStepId, lastStepId, oldStep, user
MATCH (s:Step {id: firstStepId})
MATCH (s2:Step {id: lastStepId})
MERGE (user)-[:LAST_STEP]->(s)
WITH s2, collect(oldStep) AS old
FOREACH (x IN old | MERGE (s2)-[:NEXT]->(x))
```

[image]

Comment: And if you have apoc you can use `apoc.nodes.link(nodes, "NEXT")`

Comment: I prefer people learn Cypher before APOC :) but yes APOC FTW !

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen thank you, I do have a uuid but was just giving an example. This works perfectly, I'll look into an APOC when I am in more need for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a couple of APOC procedures to create the nodes and then link them together:

- `apoc.create.nodes` can be used to create multiple nodes with the same label(s).
- `apoc.nodes.link` can be used to chain the nodes together with relationships of the same type.

For example, the query below will create your 3 sample nodes (with a `Step` label) and then link them together, in order, with `has_next_step` relationships:

```
CALL apoc.create.nodes(['Step'],[{name:'step1'},{name:'step2'},{name: 'step3'}]) YIELD node
WITH COLLECT(node) AS nodes
CALL apoc.nodes.link(nodes, 'has_next_step')
RETURN SIZE(nodes)
```

The `apoc.nodes.link` procedure does not return anything, so the above query just returns the number of nodes that were created and linked together.